# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region" error for JAR built via IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, aws-sdk

I'm using IntelliJ to develop an AWS app (simply retrieves from SecretsManager). I'm able to run the app fine in IntelliJ, but when I build a JAR artifact via IntelliJ and try to execute the JAR, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region`.

I built the JAR via IntelliJ, but I use a `pom.xml` to specify the dependencies. When I try to execute the JAR, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region` error. I've included this dependency as part of my `pom.xml`, and I have also verified that the JAR is extracting the "software.amazon.awssdk.regions" library.

I have no idea why the JAR complains about "ClassNotFoundException", when the class it's looking for is literally in the JAR?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

I've included my `pom.xml` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.chronoslabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>chronos-trader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jmockit/jmockit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.binance</groupId>
            <artifactId>binance-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.knowm.xchange/xchange-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.knowm.xchange/xchange-stream-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-stream-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.knowm.xchange/xchange-stream-service-netty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-stream-service-netty</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.knowm.xchange/xchange-binance -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>xchange-binance</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/secretsmanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>regions</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.38</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

        <aws.java.sdk.version>2.20.38</aws.java.sdk.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Be aware of [BOM recommendation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2#importing-the-bom) and [issues/884](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/884).

Answer (score 0):

What ended up helping me was the `maven-assembly-plugin`. This will create a JAR with all of the dependencies bundled.

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```